# NSFetchedResultsController not updating?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data

When my user sees a picture, she can like it by pressing a button. The following code is run:

```
- (void)feedback:(Item *)item isLiked:(bool)liked {
    // Update the item with the new score asynchornously
    NSManagedObjectID *itemId = item.objectID;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Create a new managed object context and set its persistent store coordinator
        // Note that this **must** be done here because this context belongs to another thread
        AppDelegate *theDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [localContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[theDelegate persistentStoreCoordinator]];

        Item *localItem = (Item *)[localContext objectWithID:itemId];
        localItem.liked = [NSNumber numberWithBool:liked];
        localItem.updated_at = [NSDate date];
        NSError *error;
        if (![localContext save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Error saving: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    });
```

In my app, LikedViewController shows the images that the user has liked. LikedVC consists of a UITableViewController hooked up to an NSFetchedResultsController.

LikedVC:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // NSFetchedResultsController
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
    _fetchedResultsController = \
    [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:[self.delegate getFetchRequest]
                                        managedObjectContext:moc
                                          sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                   cacheName:nil];  // TODO investigate whether we should bother with cache
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    NSError *error;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
        // Update to handle the error appropriately.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        exit(-1);  // Fail
    }

    // Bottom loading bar
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = self.footerView;
    self.footerActivityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true;

    // ActivityIndicator
    self.activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    self.activityIndicator.color = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.tableView addSubview:self.activityIndicator];
    self.activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true;
    // FIXME Unable to center it inside the tableView properly
    self.activityIndicator.center = CGPointMake(self.tableView.center.x, self.tableView.center.y - self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height);
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    // Automatically fetch when there is nothing in the UITableView
    if ([self tableView:self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0] == 0) {
        if ([self canFetch]) {
            [self refill];
        }
    }
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];

    if (self.operation && self.operation.isExecuting) {
        NSLog(@"Cancelling Operation: %@", self.operation);
        [self.operation cancel];
        self.isFetching = false;
    }
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"FeedCell";
    Item *item = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    FeedCell *cell = (FeedCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.item = item;
    cell.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.customImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    // NOTE Don't try to do this at the UITableViewCell level since the tap will be eaten by the UITableView/ScrollView
    if (self.likeOnTap) {
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:)];
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        [cell.customImageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    }

    // Set up the buttons
    [cell.likeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(liked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.dislikeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(disliked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.detailButton addTarget:self action:@selector(detailed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] queryDiskCacheForKey:item.image_url done:^(UIImage *image, SDImageCacheType type) {
        if (image) {
            [cell setCustomImage:image];
        } else {
            // If we have to download, make sure user is on the image for more than 0.25s before we
            // try to fetch. This prevents mass downloading when the user is scrolling really fast
            double delayInSeconds = 0.25;
            dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
            dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                if ([self isIndexPathVisible:indexPath]) {
                    [SDWebImageDownloader.sharedDownloader
                     downloadImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:item.image_url]
                     options:0
                     progress:^(NSUInteger receivedSize, long long expectedSize) { }
                     completed:^(UIImage *image, NSData *data, NSError *error, BOOL finished) {
                         if (image && finished) {
                             [cell setCustomImage:image];
                             [[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] storeImage:image forKey:item.image_url];
                         }
                     }];
                }
            });
        }
    }];

    // Check if we are almost at the end of the scroll. If so, start fetching.
    // Doing this here is better than overriding scrollViewDidEndDragging
    if (indexPath.row >= [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0] - 3) {
        [self refill];
    }

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id sectionInfo = [_fetchedResultsController.sections objectAtIndex:section];
    NSInteger ret = [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
    self.hasContent = (ret != 0);
    return ret;
}


# pragma mark - NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate

- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    NSLog(@"1");
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {
    NSLog(@"2");
    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {
    NSLog(@"3");
    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [NSException raise:@"Unknown update" format:@"NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate: invoked"];
            // [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [NSException raise:@"Unknown update" format:@"NSFetchedResultsChangeMove: invoked"];
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    NSLog(@"4");
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

(Note that I have omitted some info to keep this question short)

This is the fetchRequest of LikedVC

```
- (NSFetchRequest *)getFetchRequest {
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Item" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
    [request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"liked == %d OR origin == %d", 1, OriginsLike]];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    [request setResultType:NSManagedObjectResultType];
    [request setFetchBatchSize:10];
    NSSortDescriptor *d = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"updated_at" ascending:NO selector:nil];
    [request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:d]];
    return request;
}
```

I am seeing a bug where the user has liked a item, but then when the user switches over to LikedVC the item is not shown anywhere.

I added NSLog(@"1"), NSLog(@"2"), ... in the tableView's controllerDidChangeContent, controllerWillChangeContent, etc methods. I do not see "1", "2", .. being logged at all.

Why is my NSFetchedResultsController not working?

Comment: I read through a couple times so I had to ask: what are you expecting to happen here? 

User clicks like, and `- (void)feedback:(Item *)item isLiked:(bool)liked` is fired and you state that it works properly. 

The `LikedViewController` picks up the `Item` that was just liked. Where does your picture come in? is it referenced in the `Item` object? 

I'm not a huge expert on NSFetchedController, but I don't think it is firing events the way you expect it to, and seems like its working as intended if the `liked` results are returning correctly.... ?

Comment: @twairball Updated the question. Basically, feedback is fired. I **think** feedback has been executed correctly. NSFetchedResultsController is not updating because I don't see the new item being shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Direct Answer**

The direct answer to your question is you need to observe  `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` and merge the changes from your temporary context into the main context that the `NSFetchedResultsController` is observing. It's best to do this in whatever object owns your main context. Looks like you're using your app delegate.

You merged the data as follows:

```
- (void)managedObjectContextDidSave:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // if the notification is on a background thread, forward it to the main thread
    if (![NSThread isMainThread]) {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(managedObjectContextDidSave:) withObject:notification];
        return;
    }

    // if a context other than the main context has saved, merge the changes
    if (notification.object != self.managedObjectContext) {
        [self.managedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
    }
}
```

**Your code seems suspect**

All of your logic happens on the main queue so you don't really need another context at all. There's also no real benefit to using `dispatch_async` on the main queue in this case. If you keep everything on the main thread just create and save the new object directly into the main context. If you really do want things to be asynchronous, the use dispatch_async to dispatch the block to a background queue and then you would need a new context (as you have implemented) for the background thread.